# How to count color patterns in excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 6 columns and about 247 rows. each of these rows has integers in each column that are colored either red, yellow, or blue. This indicates that the number in each cell is either hot, med, or cold for the number of times it has appeared. I would like to count patterns. So if there is a row that appears (blue, yellow, yellow, yellow, red, yellow) i would like to have a count on how many times that pattern happens. It has to be column specific for the color. I have a set of columns and rows with all possible patterns and would like to have the count show up by the pattern it corresponds with. So maybe a compare would work? It has been a long time since i have used VBA. If there is an answer for this already, i apologize but my searches have not turned anything up. Thank You.

Update 2/19/2018 11:56 - added Picture.
This is the top portion of the data. The colors are not automatically populated in the cells at this point. However when new data is added the counts would have to update. 
[image]

Comment: We would need to see how your data is set up, especially how your possible patterns are set up on the worksheet. Could you provide us with a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly then the following should do what you are expecting:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
ws.Columns(14).ClearContents 
For i = 3 To lastrow 'loop from row 3 to last row with data on Column A
    Color1 = ws.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color 'get the interior color of the cell
    Color2 = ws.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color
    Color3 = ws.Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color
    Color4 = ws.Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color
    Color5 = ws.Cells(i, 5).Interior.Color
    Color6 = ws.Cells(i, 6).Interior.Color
    For x = 3 To 732
    'loop from row 3 to 732, amend this to however many color combinations you have on Columns H:M (I assumed 3 Color possibilities in 6 cells, so 3 to the power of 6 = 729)
        If Color1 = ws.Cells(x, 8).Interior.Color And Color2 = ws.Cells(x, 9).Interior.Color And _
        Color3 = ws.Cells(x, 10).Interior.Color And Color4 = ws.Cells(x, 11).Interior.Color And _
        Color5 = ws.Cells(x, 12).Interior.Color And Color6 = ws.Cells(x, 13).Interior.Color Then
        'if all 6 colors match then
            ws.Cells(x, 14) = Val(ws.Cells(x, 14)) + 1
        End If
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where does the count get stored? Should be in the Total column where it would indicate that the pattern matches (x amount of times). I ran the code and it seems to not produce anything. Also sorry i am missing a column in the "Pattern Combinations" H - M should be colors and then data would go in column N.

Comment: The Total Count would go on Column N as you mentioned,... How are the cells colored in, by using the Fill color or using Conditional Formatting?

Comment: I have it working now. It was because i did not have the last row of colors on the chart. Anyway of clearing the counts when it is run? Currently if i run the code again it just doubles the counts. I would have to clear the cells each time i run it. thanks

Comment: @ScottPurtan Updated my answer to clear the contents of Column N before running the code again. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I may offer an alternative to Xabier's answer, I think the way to go is to give each row pattern a unique reference.

We can assign a number to the row using boolean algebra. The below code will add a column of reference numbers that correspond to the pattern of coloured cells in the row.

You'll need to change the values of the three variables `cold`, `med` and `hot` to the corresponding colour values of the cells. You can find this using `range.interior.color`

```
 Sub cellcolor()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim firstrow As Long, lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim ptn As Long
    Dim cold As Long: cold = 9851952  'Replace with your own colour
    Dim med As Long: med = 49407      'Replace with your own colour
    Dim hot As Long: hot = 192        'Replace with your own colour

    'Find the first row
    firstrow = 1
    Do While Cells(firstrow, "A") = ""
        firstrow = firstrow + 1
    Loop

    'Find the last row
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Find the last column
    lastcol = Cells(firstrow, "A").End(xlToRight).Column

    For x = firstrow To lastrow
        ptn = 0
        For y = 1 To lastcol
            Select Case Cells(x, y).Interior.Color
                Case cold
                    ptn = ptn + (2 ^ ((3 * y - 2) - 1))
                Case med
                    ptn = ptn + (2 ^ (3 * y - 2))
                Case hot
                    ptn = ptn + (2 ^ ((3 * y - 2) + 1))
            End Select
        Next y
        'Print the result to the column right of the last column
        Cells(x, lastcol + 1).Value = ptn
     Next x
 End Sub
```

The same approach can be applied to the list of pattern combinations, giving each row a unique number corresponding to its pattern (offset the value of `y`, ex. `y+7` and change `lastcol`). These numbers can then be cross-referenced with the results from the original list using `=COUNTIF()` to tell you how many times it has occurred.